# Dependency issues with ionic plugins

Tags: ionic5

When I'm trying to install camera plugin in ionic 5 ,it throws error

[ng] An unhandled exception occurred: The target entry-point "@ionic-native/camera" has missing dependencies:
[ng]  - @ionic-native/core
[ng] See "C:\Users\salini\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-PiL6u3\angular-errors.log" for further details.
not only camera whatever plugin may be it throws error.

If any one experience the same issue or know the solution please let me know.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

You could try doing - `npm install @ionic-native/core`. It should solve your issue.